# get current action in controllers or views file

Tags: php, laravel

Whill working with Yii I see it does offer convenient methods to retreive the current action. Is that method available in Laravel?

Thank you.

Comment: -1 for not reading the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Request::route()->controller_action
```

The `Request::route()` returns the route object for current request. You will find routing details inside this object. If its not a controller route rather a closure route then `Request::route()->controller_action` will be null.